# Почему не работает метод filter в моем случает?

Tags: javascript, filter

```js
let heroes = [{
    name: 'Bob'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sara'
  }
];
let searchItem = 'Bo';
const visibleHeroes = heroes.filter(hero => {
  hero.name.includes(searchItem)
});
console.log(visibleHeroes);
```

Comment: let heroes = [
    {
        name: 'Bob'
    },
    {
        name: 'Bobby'
    },
    {
        name: 'Sara'
    }
    ];
    let searchItem = 'Bo';
    const visibleHeroes = heroes.filter(hero =>{
      hero.name.includes(searchItem)
     });
    console.log(visibleHeroes);

Comment: какая ошибка в консоли?

Answer (score 2):

`Arrow functions` - или `hero => {return value;}`или `hero => value`

```js
'use strict';
let heroes = [{
    name: 'Bob'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sara'
  }
];
let searchItem = 'Bo';
// 
let visibleHeroes = heroes.filter(hero => hero.name.includes(searchItem));
console.log(visibleHeroes);
```

[Док](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)